# Figma plugin for Bootstrap's "mix" function for tints &shades

Tags: interface-design, figma, plugin

Is there a Figma plugin for generating tints & shades of a color that would be the same as the ones produced by Bootstrap's "mix" function (as shown here —  https://codepen.io/emdeoh/pen/zYOQOPB)?

I've tried some Figma plugins that generate tints / shades, but the results seem to differ from what I'd get through that Codepen snippet.

Thanks!